# Datepicker not working while creating special price

Tags: magento-1, backend, adminform, special-price, datepicker

Whenever I am trying to create a special price for a product and try to select the from and to dates for the same the date is not getting selected at all, I have to enter it manually every time. How can I correct this?

Comment: inspect the datepicker try to find problem may be missing/confict  calender.js file.

Comment: Try a different browser...

Comment: any js (javascript) error?

Comment: @Badger Tried in different browser but the date picker is not still working.

Comment: @Anja Tried inspecting the element and also reloaded the page to check whether I will get any js error in browser console but didn't get any.

Answer (score 0):

So date fields are added using **Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date**. What you could do would be to look into this file and check the function **getElementHtml**

I did  in c.e 1.8.1 and found that the z-index was empty. I'm assuming it's being attached to the dom wrong, as it's using some khtml browser speciality code. Anyways, I got it working again by adding

```
cal.element.style.zIndex = 99999;
```

in **calendar-setup.js**

Comment: Tried to find the problem in it but could not. I even replaced the file content with the content of a Magento store where the date picker is working properly but it did not make any difference.

Comment: ok try this.. rply if it's work or not. ?

Comment: there is no z-index variable in the calendar-setup.js, I checked to update the value there.

Comment: I tried adding as you suggested but the box is still empty even after i selected a date it is not getting selected and filled up.

Comment: problem is date doesn't select ?

Comment: yes the date doesn't get selected

Comment: Please mention which Magento you used.. 1.x or 2.x ??

Comment: 1.9.2 is the version i am using